# Why are Jews avoiding giving the name Jethro to their sons?

Tags: yisro--the-man

How come the name "Jethro" is not given to Jews?  Wasn't he a good guy in the end?

Comment: Maybe it was, but went out of use, like Ishmael.

Comment: @Gary -- For Ishmael, there was a reason: The advent of Islam.  But for Jethro?

Comment: That group was known as Ishmaelites long before the rise of Islam--maybe there was another reason?  After all, Joshua and its variants didn't stop being used after the advent of that other religion several hundred years earlier...maybe it's just the way names change in popularity over the years--not too many newborn Dottys, Yettas, Morrises, and Clydes around these days...plenty of Tylers and Perrys around, though.

Comment: Indeed, there's no shortage of women named "Ruth"

Comment: Yisro went back to his people shortly after his conversion to Judaism. He did not integrate with the Israelites. Jews generally name their children after outstanding members of their own people.